# Connect users to a Django website with React-Native

Tags: django, react-native

I have a Django website running, where users can login, save data, take notes, etc. I want to make a mobile app for this website and I am looking into react-native, as I made my website front end with React-JS.

I want to be able to fetch users data on the website from the app. I saw that React-Native had the `fetch` function, similar to AJAX calls. The problem is that I need the user to be authenticated for the POST call to return something, as I am reading the `request.user` value to grab the proper data. I also know that without the proper csrf token, Django won't allow a POST call.

How can I do a fetch with the proper `request.user` value and pass the csrf security test from the react-native app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your mobile application, I would create first of all and API with [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). In authentication, you should use [`Token Authentication`](http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2015/10/27/how-to-use-django-rest-frameworks-token-based-authentication) so in each request will have the follow hearder `Authorization: Token user_token`. With this token you can identidy the user as usual using `request.user` in your views.
In React-Native, you should use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to do the request for login( to get the token) and them the user data:

```
const config = {
   headers: {
     'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken'),
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
 };
 axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}api/users/data/`, config_user)
   .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data) // User Data
    });
```